# Measure of solid angle in n-dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let us define $V = (v_1,...,v_n)$ a set of $n$ unit-vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Each pair of vector has angle $\theta$ such that $\cos(\theta) = \frac{-1}{n}$.

I consider the subset $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x = \lambda_1 v_1 + \dots + \lambda_n v_n, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}^+ \}$.

I would like to get:

1. the solid angle (n-dimensional angle) spanned by $\Omega$?
2. the gaussian measure $\gamma_n$ of $\Omega$: is it similar, by rotation invariance of the gaussian measure, to the solid angle of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

A hint: a geometrical view.

Value $\theta=\cos^{-1}(-1/n)$ is characteristic of the $n$ dimensional [simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555278/305862).

Some more precision. Let $v_k=\vec{OP_k}$.

Points $P_k$ are $n$ among the $n+1$ points of "the" standard regular simplex of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

The lacking $n+1$st point $P_0$ can be defined in this way:

$$\vec{OP_0}=- \sum_{k=1}^n \vec{OP_k}$$

Let us consider the case $n=3$ ; the solid angle you are looking for is the area of a certain spherical triangle "cutted off" on the unit sphere by the triangular pyramid whose edges are directed by the $\vec{OP_k}, k=1,2,3$.

For symmetry reasons this solid angle is one among the four "identical" (I should say isometric) solid angles that can be created in this way. Therefore, the solid angle you are looking for is the whole solid angle ($4 \pi$) divided by $4$ giving $\pi$ as the final result.

It remains to extrapolate this 3D configuration to nD, with caution, because $n$-dimensional situations can be very counter-intuitive. In particular, you have to look for formulas for the $n$ dimensional sphere : what is the equivalent of its surface, etc.

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3226170/305862

Comment: Thanks Jean-Marie! There was actually a typo in my statement: I have $\cos^{-1}(\theta) = \frac{-1}{n+1}$. I managed to get a lower-bound by considering $\theta > \pi/2$. I thus have $\gamma(\Omega) > \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. Does it seem correct?

Comment: No, in $\mathbb{R^n}$, it is $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(-\tfrac{1}{\color{red}{n}}\right)$.